# Error converting HTML/CSS to PDF using PHP

Tags: php, pdf-generation, barcode

I build bar codes using jquery in a div in my web app.
The black bars are contructed as a set of div tags with their background as black or white as follows,

```
<div style='padding: 0px; overflow: auto; width: 194px;' id='bar1'>
  <div style='float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 40px; width: 60px'>
  <div style='float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: 2px solid #000000; height: 40px;'>
```

I have tried multiple PHP packages (htmp2pdf, dompdf, tcpdf) to convert this to PDF but come up with either a blank PDF or an error as it sees nested div in the content.
Can anyone tell me how can I convert these generated barcodes to PDF suing PHP?

Comment: did you make sure that all the div tags were closed? Did you try to do it by not using inline css?

Comment: Yes, it renders fine in HTML but has problems when I convert to PDF

Answer (score 0):

Try [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) which is a simple shell utility to convert html to pdf using the webkit rendering engine.

To use it, unpack it and run it like this:

> > wkhtmltopdf www.mydomain.com/barcode3 barcode3.pdf

Basically, it will run over *n* HTML pages and generate PDF's without the overhead of purely dynamic PDF generation!

This might offer you a solution, but you'll need to check the requirements and see if it fits with your server constraints. It worked really well when we used it for producing accurate reports directly from HTML.

**EDIT: EG, running it as a potential user function from within PHP:**

**For Linux:**

```
exec("wkhtmltopdf http://mydomain.com /home/user/$user.barcode3.pdf 2>&1");
```

**For Windows:**

```
<?php
exec('C://path/to/package//wkhtmltopdf http://mydomain.html barcode3.pdf');

echo "PDF Created Successfully";
?>
```

Comment: This would not fit my need since I actually need to provide the users of my web app the feature to convert the barcodes they generate to pdf

Comment: You could provide a PHP-driven user function that automates the usage of this package using the PHP `exec()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Would it help if you used <img> data instead of drawing the bars with <div> rectangles? Not sure if you need Code 128 or another symbology, but there is a complete set of inline (base64) Code 128 images at http://notionovus.com/blog/code-128-barcode/.

I initially tried to generate barcodes by drawing rectangles, but found that letting the browser do the scaling saved me a lot of work. Sounds like the <div> tags have their down side as well.